# Navigation Search Bar

Tags: navigation, swift4.2

So I want to be able to put a search bar in my navigation bar. The problem is I don't have any space and was wondering if I could make the navigation bar hold more items.
I was trying to make something like this (but all in a navigation controller)

[image: Text]

This is what I tried... but it made no change

```
let searchBar = UITextField()
searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(searchBar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code

```
var searchController = UISearchController()
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

// Include the search bar within the navigation bar.
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```